# What's the correct platform to offer Microsoft SSO for a SaaS app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, microsoft-oauth

Our SaaS application offers SSO from Google and Okta, and now we'd like to add Microsoft, but it's unclear to me which platform is the correct one. I see these:

Active Directory Federation Services
Azure Active Directory (same?)
Microsoft Entra
Microsoft identity platform

What I need: Our SSO process only supports OAuth, and our customers typically also use SSO to log in to their Sales and Marketing tools, e.g., MS Dynamics. It looks like "identity platform" might the right choice, but I'm not certain. Can anyone advise?

Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft identity platform (formerly known as Azure AD v2.0) would be the most suitable choice.